# How to take value from Django form?

Tags: python, html, css, django, django-forms

I have a form with one field for choosing a method to sort objects. However, when I refer to this field to get it's value, it equals to HTML code that renders out this form. How do I solve this problem?

My form:

```
class sortChoice(forms.Form):
    CHOICES = [('sbd', 'Сортировать по дате'),
                ('sbp', 'Сортировать по популярности')]
    choice = forms.ChoiceField(choices = CHOICES, widget = forms.RadioSelect, label = 'Сортировка по')
```

My view:

```
@login_required(login_url = 'login')

def vacancyListView(request):
    searchQueryNavbar = request.GET.get('search_navbar', '')
    searchQueryVLpage = request.GET.get('search_vlpage', '')
    form = sortChoice()
    print(form['choice'])
    if searchQueryNavbar or searchQueryVLpage:
        if searchQueryNavbar:
            searchQuery = searchQueryNavbar
        else:
            searchQuery = searchQueryVLpage
        if form['choice'] == 'sbp':
            queryset = Vacancy.objects.filter(Q(name__icontains = searchQuery) | Q(salary__icontains = searchQuery) | Q(competences__icontains = searchQuery)).order_by('-viewsAmount')
        if form['choice'] == 'sbd':
            queryset = Vacancy.objects.filter(Q(name__icontains = searchQuery) | Q(salary__icontains = searchQuery) | Q(competences__icontains = searchQuery)).order_by('-creationDate')
    else:
        queryset = Vacancy.objects.all().order_by('-viewsAmount')
    context = {
        'objectList':queryset,
        'form':form
    }
    return render(request, "vacancyList.html", context)
```

Console output of `print(from['choice'])`:

```
<ul id="id_choice">

    <li><label for="id_choice_0"><input type="radio" name="choice" value="sbd" required id="id_choice_0">
 Сортировать по дате</label>
</li>
    <li><label for="id_choice_1"><input type="radio" name="choice" value="sbp" required id="id_choice_1">
 Сортировать по популярности</label>
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This seems normal for a `RadioSelect`. What's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to assign data to your form. See [Bound and unbound forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#module-django.forms)

```
form = sortChoice(request.POST or request.GET)
```

After call [**`form.is_valid()`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.is_valid), you will be able to access [**`cleaned_data`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.cleaned_data).

And then your code is something like this:

```
@login_required(login_url = 'login')
def vacancyListView(request):
    searchQueryNavbar = request.GET.get('search_navbar', '')
    searchQueryVLpage = request.GET.get('search_vlpage', '')
    form = sortChoice(request.POST or request.GET)
    if searchQueryNavbar or searchQueryVLpage:
        if searchQueryNavbar:
            searchQuery = searchQueryNavbar
        else:
            searchQuery = searchQueryVLpage
        if form.is_valid():
            selected = form.cleaned_data.get("choice")
            if selected == 'sbp':
                queryset = Vacancy.objects.filter(Q(name__icontains = searchQuery) | Q(salary__icontains = searchQuery) | Q(competences__icontains = searchQuery)).order_by('-viewsAmount')
            if selected == 'sbd':
                queryset = Vacancy.objects.filter(Q(name__icontains = searchQuery) | Q(salary__icontains = searchQuery) | Q(competences__icontains = searchQuery)).order_by('-creationDate')
    else:
        queryset = Vacancy.objects.all().order_by('-viewsAmount')
    context = {
        'objectList':queryset,
        'form':form
    }
    return render(request, "vacancyList.html", context)
```

**I would change the choice keys as following**:

```
CHOICES = [
    ('creationDate', 'Сортировать по дате'),
    ('viewsAmount', 'Сортировать по популярности')
]
```

then you don't have to use `if else` and do like this:

```
queryset = Vacancy.objects.filter(
    Q(name__icontains = searchQuery) | Q(salary__icontains = searchQuery) | Q(competences__icontains = searchQuery)
).order_by('-%s' % form.cleaned_data.get("choice"))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but `cleaned_data` somehow ends up with and empty string corresponding to `choice` value, therefore it does not work, as empty string is obviously not equal to any of the choices. Why does it happen?

Comment: @ventisk1ze, did you mean that `form.cleaned_data.get("choice")` is `None`,  what did you see in `form.cleaned_data`. If your form is valid  then form.cleaned_data.get("choice") can't be empty because choice field is required.

Comment: @ventisk1ze, how did you send your data? Show your template.html.

Comment: I added `required = False` to form field, 'cos in the other way `form.is_valid()` returns False.

Comment: my `form.cleaned_data.get('choice')` is not `None`, it's empty string. I ran `print(selected == None)` and in returned `False`.

Comment: @ventisk1ze, what did you see in `print(form.data)`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230378/discussion-between-nksm-and-ventisk1ze).